# Is it necessary to understand C# before going into ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Do I have to get some C# class before taking ASP.Net programming lessons?

Comment: Depend on you.  Do you have C or C++ background? Java?  ALready know web programming?  You're going to be learning a lot of things at once on this path.  Maybe you want to crawl first, then walk, then run.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the latter "c#" was meant to be "ASP.NET" - I think it's highly advisable.

If you try to learn a language *and* a UI platform at the same time, you won't know whether problems you run into are due to not understanding the language or not understanding the UI technology.

I would suggest learning C# first - via console apps, with collections, IO etc - and then moving on to ASP.NET afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET server side programming you'll definitely need to know either C# or VB.NET. I prefer C#, but it depends on your background. If you've done a lot of VBA, you may be more comfortable learning VB.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use C# as a language of choice it is strongly recommended to take lessons in C# and OOP. If you start directly with ASP.NET you risk to end up with horribly unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some programming background you don't need high skill is C#.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is a GUI programming language only. Under the hood, it is either C# or VBNET that does the real job as accessing the underlying datastores and playing with your objects. As a matter of fact, when you code your Page_Load() method, it is C#/VBNET that you code.

I would advise anyone wanting to go ASP.NET to have a minimum of C# or VBNET knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

yes the asp.net require the c# programming code as c# is required in the all the gui based coding . for the proper creation of the asp pages it is must for the programmer to have the knowledge of c# .

Comment: c# is must only if u opt it as the preferred programming language in your programs . you can also use the vb as the programming language

Answer (score 0):

I think C# should be done first as it is the basic language background for ASP.NET applications. C# can be used separately also, so I say C# should be started with console applications and more in order to understand ASP.NET as a HIGH TECH PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE.

Comment: Well, ASP.NET is not a programming language, and you can use it with other languages than C# as well.